# PHP how to open the .doc and .docx files?

Tags: php

doc files

```
$filename = 'ahfdghasfdh.doc';
header('Content-type: application/msword');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="testqq"');
@readfile($filename);
```

I tried this code its not working. How to open the .doc files on browser using php.

Comment: The `@` you're using suppresses error messages if `readfile` throws an error. It's obviously unhelpful to suppress error messages when you're trying to debug code that isn't working. Remove the `@` and check what errors you get.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
<?php
$filename = 'ahfdghasfdh.doc';
header('Content-disposition: inline');
header('Content-type: application/msword'); // not sure if this is the correct MIME type
readfile($filename);
exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open as like that:

```
<a href="yourfile.doc">MSWORD FILE</a>
```

And other solution @vinod already shared

And if you just want to open doc file on browser no application involved than I recommend to use **GOOGLE** **DOCS.**